# No se guardan las imágenes en la ruta con faker

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Buenas noche amigos como van, la cuestión es la siguiente no se  que pasa al guardar una imagen(picture) con faker, los demás datos se guardan común corriente pero al guardarlos y generar un seed de un usuario en la tabla user se guarda de la siguiente manera como muestra la imgen, adjunto el archivo factories y seeds de user.

No se crean el directorio users en app\public pensé que era permisos pero tampoco sirvió con un chmod 777 o 755 -R

Note: El paquete que manejo es intervetion image

En el archivo config filesystem cambie el path a public
'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'public'),

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @Jheyner. Considere reemplazar la imagen por el código. Puedes consultar [Ayuda de edición de Markdown](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Te ayudará mucho para publicar tu código acá y mejorar las oportunidades de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Tu imagen se encuentra en la carpeta `tuproyecto/public/app/public/users` ? Porque es donde está apuntando el método image, revisa que la imagen se encuentre ahí y luego continuamos ;)

Comment: Veo que se me creo una carpeta en el storage/app/public/users ahi deberia de ir o como hago para cambiar la ruta del storage_path()

Comment: La ruta que se guarda es esta storage\app\public\users pero la imagen que se crea esta rota. No se muestra y en la base de datos guarda en el campo picture el valor de 0 y a demas al hacer migrate:fresh --seed se queda pensando o cargando por mucho tiempo.